# converting list of strings and getting the total as integer

Tags: python, python-3.x, for-loop

I have a list of integers stored as strings and would like to convert it and get its total in integer and they print the total.

What is the easiest way to do that?

The list is as follow:

```
string_numbers = ['55','63','43','44']
```

I want to create it in a for-loop.

thanks

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There you go:

```
string_numbers = ['55','63','43','44']

total = 0
for item in string_numbers:
    total = total + int(item)

print(total)
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use the builtin functions `sum` and `map`.
Map is a functional equivalent of a for loop.

```
>>> string_numbers = ['55','63','43','44']
>>> sum(map(int, string_numbers))
205
```

You can also use a generator expression instead of `map`.

```
>>> sum(int(n) for n in string_numbers)
```

Answer (score 0):

Using *list comprehension*

```
print(sum([int(i) for i in string_numbers]))
# 205
```

Using *functools.reduce*

```
from functools import reduce
print(reduce(lambda x, y: int(x) + int(y), string_numbers))
# 205
```

Expanded loop:

```
total = []
for i in string_numbers:
    total.append(int(i))
print(sum(total))
```